# can i print out a int without doing calculation for me (with the ‘+’ symbol and two number on the back and front) in c?

Tags: c

```
char *menu[SIZE];
menu[0] = "Nasi Lemak + Teh Tarik";
menu[1] = "Prawn Mee";//there is lots more down here
int calories[SIZE];
calories[0] = 644 + 83;
calories[1] = 239;
int index;
for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    printf("%d. ", index + 1);
    printf("%s", menu[index]);
    int tab;
    tab = 7 - ((strlen(menu[index]) + 3) / 8);
    while (tab != 0)//to look nice only
    {
        printf("\t");
        tab--;
    }
    printf("%d", calories[index]); //here what is needed to add?
    printf("\n");
}
```

[SAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjcPN.png)

I would like it to look like "Nasi Lemak + Teh Tarik 644 + 83" (if I needed to change to string then how to do it?)

Anyways is just fine without it, just my OCD strangling me.

Comment: you need to keep `644` and `83` in separate variables (or separate array indexes), eg `int maincalories[2] = {644, 239}; int extracalories[2] = {83, 0}; /*...*/ printf("%d + %d", maincalories[0], extracalories[0]);`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will calculate `644 + 83` at compile time and this will be assigned to `calories[0]`.

The choice of the solution depends on want you want to do with the values besides printing them.

As a simple solution to print the calories as `644 + 83` you can change the type of the `calories` array to `char* calories[SIZE]` and use it in the same way as `menu`.

```
char *menu[SIZE];
menu[0] = "Nasi Lemak + Teh Tarik";
menu[1] = "Prawn Mee";//there is lots more down here
char *calories[SIZE];
calories[0] = "644 + 83";
calories[1] = "239";
int index;
for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    printf("%d. ", index + 1);
    printf("%s", menu[index]);
    int tab;
    tab = 7 - ((strlen(menu[index]) + 3) / 8);
    while (tab != 0)//to look nice only
    {
        printf("\t");
        tab--;
    }
    printf("%s", calories[index]); //here what is needed to add?
    printf("\n");
}
```

But instead of using two separate arrays connected by the index I would use a structure.

```
struct dish {
    const char *name;
    const char *calories;
};

struct dish menu[SIZE] = {
    { "Nasi Lemak + Teh Tarik", "644 + 83" },
    { "Prawn Mee", "239" },
}

int index;
for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    printf("%d. ", index + 1);
    printf("%s", menu[index].name);
    int tab;
    tab = 7 - ((strlen(menu[index].name) + 3) / 8);
    while (tab != 0)//to look nice only
    {
        printf("\t");
        tab--;
    }
    printf("%s", menu[index].calories);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Another option would be to add more than one element for `name` and `calories` and maybe a count to each `menu` entry and use loops to print the individual strings and numbers separated by `+`.

Or (3rd option) you could use an array of `calories` values and consider a value of 0 as end of the list.

```
struct dish {
    const char *name;
    int calories[MAX_CALORIES];
};

struct dish menu[SIZE] = {
    { "Nasi Lemak + Teh Tarik", 644, 83, 0 },
    { "Prawn Mee", 239, 0 },
}

int index;
for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    printf("%d. ", index + 1);
    printf("%s", menu[index].name);
    int tab;
    tab = 7 - ((strlen(menu[index].name) + 3) / 8);
    while (tab != 0)//to look nice only
    {
        printf("\t");
        tab--;
    }
    printf("%d", menu[index].calories[0]);
    for(int i = 1; (i < MAX_CALORIES) && (menu[index].calories[i] != 0); i++)
    {
       printf(" + %d", menu[index].calories[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```